# Show div with Jquery on hover with multiple class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to show one div2 slowly when I hover a div1 associated in the same div.
I do not see where the problem is in my jquery...

```js
$(".div").hover(function() {

  $(this).find(".div2").animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".div2").animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
});
```

```css
.div2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.div` doesn't exist. Try `$("div")` instead. Also, if you only want to show the `.div2` directly after a `.div1` then you could use CSS for this. Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are targeting `$('.div')` and not `$('.div1')` or `$('div')`. There is no element with class `.div` in your code, so this is probably a typo.

You also have to change `.find()` to `.next()` if you want to trigger the event when hovering over a `'.div1'` element, since you want to target the next sibling, and not a child.

Here's a working sample you can go by:

https://jsbin.com/vipifolahe/edit?html,js,output

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
         <div class="div1">
         </div>
         <div class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div class="div1">
         </div>
         <div class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div class="div1">
         </div>
         <div class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".div1").hover(function () {

  $(this).next(".div2").animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
}, function () {
  $(this).next(".div2").animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
});
```

---

If you want to trigger the event when the parent div is hovered over, it could look like so:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="parent">
         <div class="div1">
         </div>
         <div class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
         <div class="div1">
         </div>
         <div class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
         <div class="div1">
         </div>
         <div class="div2">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".parent").hover(function () {

  $(this).find(".div2").animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
}, function () {
  $(this).find(".div2").animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, {
    queue: false
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[**The Demo is Here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=70d9fdda5216d8d1a7a863c8d13e8a1f)

JS Code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.div1').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next('.div2').css('opacity','1');
  });
  $('.div1').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).next('.div2').css('opacity','0');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to a CSS only solution you can use the [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```css
.div2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.div1, .div2 {
  border: 3px solid pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.div1:hover + .div2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no such element with class `div`, so you are not selecting any of the divs. To each `div` wrapping up divs to hover, add class that will binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. Please see snippet below:

```js
$(".wrapper").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".div2").animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".div2").animate({
        opacity: "0"
    }, {
        queue: false
    });
});
```

```css
.div2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="div1">one
         </div>
         <div class="div2">one hidden
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div class="div1">two
         </div>
         <div class="div2">two hidden
         </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div class="div1">three
         </div>
         <div class="div2">three hidden
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```